# htaccess rule for any

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a htaccess rule that matches anything trailing a slash.

For example,

I have a rule that listens for /starters-and-alternators
And i would like to write another rule that listens for /starters-and-alternators/{anything}

So whenever there is a /{anything} present after the starters-and-alternators; it redirects elsewhere.

Here's my current rules:

```
RewriteRule ^starters-and-alternators$ app/core/code/miscellaneous/allstartersandalts.php%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^starters-and-alternators/$ app/core/code/miscellaneous/allstartersandalts.php%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i've solved it!

it is (.+) is what i was looking for.

```
RewriteRule ^starters-and-alternators/(.+)$ app/core/code/miscellaneous/allstartersandalts.php%{QUERY_STRING}
```